# UITableViewDataSource load asynchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uitableview

I have a `UITableView`, which should render entries divided to **sections**.
The data requires some time in processing, therefore it's done like this:

```
@interface AsyncTable()
  NSMutableArray* _alphaKeys;
@end

@implementation AsyncTable        
-(void)refreshData {
        dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{
            <load of the _alphaKeys>
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [table reloadData];
            });
        });
}
...
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [_alphaKeys count];
}
...
@end
```

Now, this works perfectly for the first time.

But my data changes sometimes and I'm calling method refreshData from notifications.
And it's starting to crash, as at time of execution of e.g. `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, and at time of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` the array may have references to different content.

Problem is with timing, let's assume 2 calls coming short after each-other:
First one is completed loading and scheduling reloadData in main thread, then second request comes and reload of data started before main thread is called...

Any recommendation how to work this around? I don't want to put everything in main thread (it works, I'm now trying to refactor application to make it more reactive)

Comment: `reloadData` sud not be called in background, its wrong way to reload the `tableView`

Comment: @muku `reloadData` is not called from background, it's called on the main thread (see the code above). Or do I miss the point? I'm trying to call reload after background processing is finished

Comment: Hi. 1) First way is refactor a code with the `NSOperation`. It is allow you to cancel the previous operation. 2) Second way is add an additional variable for tracking loading state. Before invoking the `[table reloadData]` you need to check this variable.

Comment: @Mozilla I would use approach with additional variable, but where to use it? 
`reloadData` triggers separate calls on `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and e.g. `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. They're not in the same atomic block. Most of the time crash happening because `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is attempting to access indexPath, which is not existing, as the _alphaKeys (real code is more complicated) is already started refresh. Checking the variable in such method is not the right place, or?

Comment: @Mozilla do you have a reference to use of `NSOperation` for this case? Cancelling is good option, but I still don't understand how to synchronize calls. I.e. NSOperation1 is completed and scheduling `reloadData` on main thread, now comes NSOperation2, there is nothing to cancel, but loading of table is already scheduled, and therefore main thread should wait for NSOperation2 to complete... But we don't want to block main thread...

Comment: @NickEntin See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Mozilla9/f87c04bda2e90fe2fbaf). It's a possible decision of your issue with additional variable. I suppose that method `refreshData` is invoked only from main thread.

Comment: @Mozilla, Thanks, I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by updating the data source (`_alphaKeys`) concurrently with the tableView loading.  UITableView loads asynchronously, and there's no way to tell when it's done.  However, if you change the data source and immediately call reloadData, it will do the right thing, even if the loading is in progress.  The tricks is that the change to the data has to be done on the main thread.

My answer to you is to change your code so that the background thread does its processing on one copy of the data.  When processing is complete, run a block on the main thread that copies the new data to the table view's data source and then immediately call `reloadData`.

See my modifications to your example code:

```
@interface AsyncTable()
  NSArray* _alphaKeys;  // <-- copy for data source is immutable
@end

@implementation AsyncTable        
-(void)refreshData {
        dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{
            NSMutableArray *alphaKeysCopy = [_alphaKeys mutableCopy];  // <-- Create a new array if processing does not require current state
            <load of the alphaKeysCopy>
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                _alphaKeys = [alphaKeysCopy copy];  // <-- Copy on the main thread so the table view can't see an intermediate state
                [table reloadData];
            });
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea. One additional question: 'However, if you change the data source and immediately call reloadData, it will do the right thing, even if the loading is in progress' - where did you get it? The hint from @Mozilla above works, but I'm not 100% sure about it, just as I don't know how 'reloadData' is implemented.E.g. if it's just issues bunch of async calls to get numbers of rows, draw each raw etc. in separate blocks, there is a probability that second call of my code will insert another copy of _alphaKeys in between those calls still on main queue. You don't think so?

Comment: Table view (re)loading is an implementation detail, but my experiments show that `reloadData` sets up state and triggers the process.  On successive runloops, the datasource methods (numberOfRowsInSection, numberOfSections, cellForRowAtIndexPath, etc.) are called to build the table.  If you call `reloadData` in a runloop iteration after the first call, the table simply resets and starts over.